# Automatic link creation fails with backslash at the end of the title (and other characters)

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

This is a very minor bug, but I still think it is important to point it out (maybe it was already).

I voted another question to be closed as duplicate of [PHP preg_replace \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222643/php-preg-replace)

Since the title ends with a backslash, the text generated is:

[image]

which results in

[image]

Though, linking to the question in this question (by just inserting the link) obviously creates an appropriate link. Maybe this automatic link detection / title creation should be done for comments as well, to avoid this issue (which I admit is a minor case)?

([Unfortunately it does not look like escaping the backslash (`\\`) helps in any way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127832/automatic-link-creation-fails-with-backslash-at-the-end-of-the-title#comment348173_127832)).

**Other problematic characters:**

- *Unescaped* `]` inside the title.
  As [@Konrad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph) points out, it's a problem with Markdown not fully supported in comments. Escaping the slash works well here: [php preg_replace \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222643/php-preg-replace).
- [Trailing white spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127832/automatic-link-creation-fails-with-backslash-at-the-end-of-the-title#comment363276_127832). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091051/how-to-parse-json-string-in-android) has a trailing space in the title, shouldn't those be stripped out?
  Again, this is a limitation of comment Markdown, it works fine here:
  [Link with trailing space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127832/automatic-link-creation-fails-with-backslash-at-the-end-of-the-title) .

Comment: Alright, that's it, **NO MORE MARKDOWN**.  Straw, camel, etc., you ruined it for everyone....no more network, sorry folks.  Also, in light of these bug reports we're renaming it to MarkdownDull, since we're closing up shop can won't be fixing said bugs, etc.

Comment: Ok... I will go home then `:-/` Sorry for ruining everyones day...

Comment: Test: possible duplicate of [php preg_replace &#92;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222643/php-preg-replace")

Comment: \\ test \\ test [test \\](http://enwp.org)

Comment: [this ends with an escaped backslash (``\\``) \\](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127832/automatic-link-creation-fails-with-backslash-at-the-end-of-the-title).

Comment: @Nick I don’t get it. It’s not Markdown that’s at fault here, it’s the fact that the comments *don’t* use (full-blown) Markdown. After all, it works the normal text.

Comment: @Konrad - Nor should they, the issue is that the title is not properly escaped for markdown mini, will take a look after the gym.

Comment: [Link with trailing space ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127832/automatic-link-creation-fails-with-backslash-at-the-end-of-the-title).

Comment: In regards to the whitespace: [Auto-inserted "possible duplicate" comment does not trim whitespace from question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130963)

Answer (score 1):

I "fixed" this a long time ago. Scare quotes because I cheated; here's the relevant snippet from the code:

```cs
public static class MarkdownMaker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a [markdown](http://link) that, when run through markdown, creates HTML
    /// where linkText is displayed exactly as given. In other words, an asterisk in linkText
    /// is visible as an asterisk to the user (and cannot cause unwanted italicization),
    /// a closing bracket in linkText doesn't break the link, but is actually visible as
    /// a closing bracket, etc. If markdownMini is true, it's for putting it in comments,
    /// otherwise it's for posts.
    /// </summary>
    public static string Link(string linkText, string url, bool markdownMini)
    {
        // ...
        if (markdownMini)
        {
        // ...

            // there is absolutely no way to end a comment link with a backslash
            // -- it would always escape the closing "]". So we're using an ugly
            // unicode hack -- U+2216 is Set Minus, which looks closest to a regular
            // backslash
            if (linkText.EndsWith(@"\"))
                linkText = linkText.Substring(0, linkText.Length - 1) + "\u2216";

        // ...

    }
```